# Assign value based on type comparison

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a template class that accepts, depending on the requirement, either a `double` or an `mpfr::mpreal` type. This is what I am trying to do:

```
x = ( typeid(T)==typeid(double) ? value : value.toDouble() );
```

But it complains at compile time about *cannot convert ‘const mpfr::mpreal’ to ‘double’ in assignment*. I also tried `std::is_same`, with the same errors. Is what I am trying to do forbidden, or simply wrong (or both)? Is there any way I can do this? The calls for the class are different in each file, but fixed, for example in one `.cpp` it's called as `Class<double>`, in another `Class<mpfr::mpreal>`, etc. Here's a quick test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "mpreal.h"

template<class T>
class Bla
{
private:
    double a;
public:
    Bla(const T &x) { a = (std::is_same<T, double>::value ? x : x.toDouble()); }
    void f() { std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    mpfr::mpreal x {1.0};
    double y {2.0};
    {
        Bla<mpfr::mpreal> a {Bla<mpfr::mpreal>(x)};
        a.f();
    }
    {
        Bla<double> a {Bla<double>(y)};
        a.f();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function needs to be correct regardless of which type `T` it's instantiated with.

That is, both

```
Bla(const double &x) { a = (std::is_same<double, double>::value ? x : x.toDouble()); }
```

and

```
Bla(const mpfr::mpreal &x) { a = (std::is_same<mpfr::mpreal, double>::value ? x : x.toDouble()); }
```

must be correct, and it's pretty clear that neither is – there's no implicit conversion between `double` and `mpfr::mpreal`, and `double` doesn't have a `toDouble()` member function.

A simple solution is to delegate the conversion to an overloaded function:

```
double to_double(double x) { return x; }
double to_double(mpfr::mpreal x) { return x.toDouble(); }

Bla(const T &x) 
    : a(to_double(x)) 
{
}
```

Comment: Seeing as all the answers have the functions in common, and since you and skyking answered with this first and have the same timestamps, I'll choose this one as the answer (sorry skyking). Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

This is what *cast operators* are for. Implement this in your `mpfr::mpreal` class and other classes that you want to use in the `double` context:

```
operator double() const;
```

And your assignment becomes:

```
Bla(const T &x) { a = x; }
```

Or, better yet, initializer list:

```
Bla(const T &x) : a(x) {}
```

---

As a side note what you were trying to implement looked more like a *conditional compilation*, which is usually achieved with `#ifdef` and a like. Except it won't work in your particular case as there's no pre-processor construct (that I know of, at least) which would allow you to compare types.

---

If you can't modify that external class you have two options:

1. Derive from it. Have your own class that does the conversion from the base.

Something like that:

```
class myDouble : public mpfr::mpreal{
    public:
        myDouble() : mpfr::mpreal() {}
        operator double() const {return this->toDouble();}
};
```

2. Another option is to use templatized functions and specialize them.

Something along these lines:

```
template<typename T> myToDouble(const & T);
template<> double myToDouble(const double & _d) {return _d;}
template<> double myToDouble(const mpfr::mpreal & _d) {return _d.toDouble();}
```

and then your assignment is looking like that:

```
Bla(const T &x) : a(myToDouble(x)) {}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add that outside `mpreal.h`, so as to not modify it, to keep it original?

Comment: It is, but it would look more like a hack (to my taste). You can, as suggested by another answer, add a `toDouble()` template function and specialize it for `double` and any other type you'd like to use. I'll update my answer with an example in a minute

Answer (score 2):

A conditional expression must have a single type and if the "true" and "false" expression don't have the same type they will have to be converted. Even if the condition is known at compile time this applies.

What you could have done is for example to define a `toDouble` template function that has a specialization for `double`:

```
template <typename T>
double toDouble(T const& x) {
    return x.toDouble();
}

double toDouble(double const& x) {
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just define in the class two static helper functions:

- double as parameter
- catch all template version, which calls `toDouble()` member

if `x` is not double it'll go to template version.

Here a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace mpfr
{
  struct mpreal
  {
    double const& toDouble()const
    {
      return d;
    }

    double d;
  };
}


template<class T>
class Bla
{
    double a;

    template<class U>
    auto to_double(U const& u) -> decltype(u.toDouble())
    {
      return u.toDouble();
    }

    static double const& to_double(double const& d) { return d; }

public:

    Bla(T const& x)
      : a{ to_double(x) }
    {}

    void f() { std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n'; }
};
```

---

With the same `main()` implementation as before.

```
int main()
{
    mpfr::mpreal x {1.1};
    double y {2.2};

    {
        Bla<mpfr::mpreal> a {Bla<mpfr::mpreal>(x)};
        a.f();
    }
    {
        Bla<double> a {Bla<double>(y)};
        a.f();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* this approach will also work if you pass `float` or `int`, with `is_same` machinery, it'll fail and you must explicitly catch up all type which can be implicitly converted to double.